# C++ - Randomly access lines of several text files

Tags: c++

I have 10 text files (named file0.txt to file9.txt) with arbitrary lengths and number of lines. I need to randomly pick a file, randomly access 1-3 lines from that file, process them and repeat until all the lines of all the files have been processed. This only needs to be done once. For the sake of this question let's say "process" means print the lines. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can go about doing this without loading all the text files into memory?

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Comment: Why not load them into memory? Are they too big?

Comment: if you want to process or print all the lines from a file then why you don't want to load all the files in the memory ? you can load a single file then close it, but for this you need to keep track of all the lines you have processed

Comment: Well theoretically they can be too big, which is why I'd prefer not to  load them into memory. Also, I'm not really sure where to start because I can't come up with a good way to keep track of what files/lines I have already read.

Comment: Omry Yadan's suggestion of indexing the starting positions of the lines seems like it would be a good fit for what you're trying to do. You'll have to stream over the files once to build the indices but then you can randomly select elements from the index vectors and remove them as you process them. Repeat until your indices are all empty.

Answer (score 3):

There's not really any way to 'randomly access' (in the sense that you can randomly access a vector) lines in a text file since the only way to find the lines is to search the file linearly for newlines. This means you'll at least need to stream through the files once to access lines even if you don't load them fully into memory.

You could achieve what you're describing by passing over all the files once to count the number of lines in them and then passing over them again to pull out randomly selected lines. I'm not sure what the benefit of that would be though. What are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm guessing it's a homework question - it's too weird for a real life problem.

Answer (score 2):

you can scan the file one to index where line starts, and keep that in memory (or even persist that if you need to do the same file more than once).
once you have that you can just seek into the line beginning and just read it till newline/eof before processing.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion:

1/ Make a copy of the files
2/ Erase a line when it is read
3/ update number of lines in file
That way you randomly pick a line that exist and that was not already read.

Lot of read/write...not efficient

Comment: instead of just putting a down vote, can you please be a bit more productive and explain why you disagree. I am here to share thoughts, I understand if they are not always great, so please explain why you disagree when possible